# how to give like and comment for each wall feed via graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am displaying wall using graph api. I have queries about below problems.

I would like to give "Like" functionality for each news feed post via graph API.
W would like to give "Comment" functionality for each news feed post via graph API.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [Graph Api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

.Check Documentation.There it says

> You can comment on or like any object that has a /comments or /likes connection by posting to https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/comments and https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/likes, respectively:

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957260/how-to-comment-or-like-a-photo-in-facebook-through-fbconnect-or-graph-api-in-ipho/4957872#4957872).