# Posting a comments for links iPhone

Tags: iphone, fbconnect

I am developing an app where I need to comment on a facebook comment or link posted on the wall.I am using FBConnect and Graph API for this.I tried googling it for long time but cannot fing anything helpful.
I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4957872/997043) also but was not helpful.

Please help me out.I am able to fetch the comments but how to post a comment for that particular comment is a challenge for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this:- for " how to post a comment for that particular comment/feeds

```
 NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Your Comment text here.", @"text",@"Comment_object_id", @"object_id",nil];
  [facebook requestWithMethodName:@"comments.add" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Hi,
THanks for help.But what is the type of facebook in [facebook requestWithMethodName:@""...];